# how to show profile pictures of friends in a list view?

Tags: android, facebook

i want to add profile pictures of friends in a list view along with their names. i am using the code which gives me friends name in list view. but i don't know how to show their profile pictures.i have used a login button and on its click event friends list will open. can anybody please tell.? here is the code that i have used

```
     public class LoginActivity extends Activity{

       public static final String APP_ID = "*************";
       private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
       private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
      private ProgressDialog mProgress;
      private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
      private ProgressDialog mSpinner;
      private Handler mRunOnUi = new Handler();
      String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
      private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

      public static ArrayList<String> friends ;
      String _error;

        public byte[] picture;
        public Bitmap pictureBitmap;
        TextView tv;
         Button loginButton;
        private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
        private ContextWrapper uiActivity;

       @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
       friends= new ArrayList<String>();

      tv=(TextView)LoginActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
                            loginButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_login);

                    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                      @Override
                          public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (! facebook.isSessionValid()) {         
                          facebook.authorize(LoginActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, new LoginDialogListener()); 
                        }
                     }  
              });
            }   

                    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("FB Demo App", "onActivityResult(): " + requestCode);
                   facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                 }

                     private class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {

           public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
       saveCredentials(facebook);
     getAlbumsData task = new getAlbumsData();           
          task.execute();
      mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

                                 mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", new FriendsRequestListener());

                                     }
                             });
                             }

                       private void saveCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
         }
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                           showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
                       }

                       public void onError(DialogError error) {
                           showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
                       }

                       public void onCancel() {
                           showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
                       }
                   }
                public void showToast(String string) {
         }
     public class getAlbumsData {

                            public void execute() {
        }   }
     private class FriendsRequestListener implements RequestListener {
                      String friendData;
       //Method runs when request is complete
                      public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                          Log.v("", "FriendListRequestONComplete");

                          friendData = response; 
                          Log.v("friendData--", ""+friendData);
       LoginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            try {
        //Parse JSON Data
        JSONObject json;
            json = Util.parseJson(friendData);

   JSONArray friendArray = json.getJSONArray("data");
     Log.v("friendArray--", ""+friendArray);
    for(int i = 0; i< friendArray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject frnd_obj = friendArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                          friends.add(frnd_obj.getString("name"));
                                      }
Intent ide = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,FrndActivity.class);
 ide.putStringArrayListExtra("friends", friends);
  startActivity(ide); 
} 
catch (JSONException e) {
                                      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                      e.printStackTrace();
                                  } catch (FacebookError e) {
                                      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                      e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
                              }
                          });
                      }

                      }


             }
```

Comment: if you want to show  that data in thaatactivity then pass friends list to its adapter.

Comment: And are you get your json proper data??? If yes then just make a custom adapter and pass friendlist to that adapter as a constructor and finally set that adapter to listview... Got it?

Comment: yeah the data is proper .all the freinds names are successfully shown in list view. i just want to add their profile pics with their names.. can anybody tell me pls how to do it in proper code form?

Answer (score 3):

You have to show your friend's profile picture with URL only.

You have to use only URL for showing your frnds profile picture.(This facility is given by Facebook)

you can show your friend's profile picture with **Lazy Loading** ..

**Code::::**

```
package com.facebook.me;


import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.lazylist.Friend_List_Lazy_Loading;

public class Friend_list extends Activity
{
    public static final String DATA = "data";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String FB_ID = "id";
    public static final String PICTURE = "picture";
    public static final String URL = "url";

    Friend_List_Bean friendBean;
    ArrayList<Friend_List_Bean> aryFriendList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.friend_list);

        aryFriendList = new ArrayList<Friend_List_Bean>();

        getFriendList();
    }

    private void getFriendList() 
    {
        Bundle param = new Bundle();
        param.putString("fields", "name, picture");
        AsyncFacebookRunner async = new AsyncFacebookRunner(MainActivity.facebook);
        async.request("me/friends", param, new RequestListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) 
            {
                Log.d("response : ", ""+response);
                parseContact(response);
            }
        },null);
    }
    public void parseContact(String response)
    {
        try 
        {
            JSONObject objResponse = new JSONObject(response);

            JSONArray contact = objResponse.getJSONArray(DATA);
            Log.d("Total Friends", " : "+contact.length());
            for(int i=0;i<contact.length();i++)
            {
                friendBean = new Friend_List_Bean();
                JSONObject objData = contact.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.d("", ""+objData.getString(FB_ID));
                Log.d("", ""+objData.getString(NAME));
                Log.d("", ""+objData.getString(PICTURE));

                JSONObject objJsonPicture = objData.getJSONObject(PICTURE);
                JSONObject objJsonPictureData = objJsonPicture.getJSONObject(DATA);
                Log.d("", ""+objJsonPictureData.getString(URL));

                friendBean.setFbId(objData.getString(FB_ID));
                friendBean.setName(objData.getString(NAME));
                friendBean.setPictureUrl(objJsonPictureData.getString(URL));
                aryFriendList.add(friendBean);
            }
            Intent i = new  Intent(Friend_list.this, Friend_List_Lazy_Loading.class);
            i.putExtra("aryFriendList", aryFriendList);
            startActivity(i);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**BEAN:::::**

```
package com.facebook.me;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Friend_List_Bean implements Serializable
{
    public String fbId;
    public String name;
    public String pictureUrl;
    public String getFbId() 
    {
        return fbId;
    }
    public void setFbId(String fbId) 
    {
        this.fbId = fbId;
    }
    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPictureUrl() 
    {
        return pictureUrl;
    }
    public void setPictureUrl(String pictureUrl) 
    {
        this.pictureUrl = pictureUrl;
    }

}
```

**Friend_List_Lazy_Loading.class:::**

```
package com.facebook.lazylist;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.me.Friend_List_Bean;
import com.facebook.me.Post_on_Friend;
import com.facebook.me.R;

public class Friend_List_Lazy_Loading extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    ListView list;
    GridView gv;
    LazyAdapter adapter;
    GridViewLazyAdapter gridViewLazyAdapter;

   ArrayList<Friend_List_Bean> aryFriendList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

//        aryFriendList = new ArrayList<Friend_List_Bean>();
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        Intent intent=getIntent();
         aryFriendList=(ArrayList<Friend_List_Bean>)intent.getSerializableExtra("aryFriendList");

        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, aryFriendList);
        gridViewLazyAdapter=new GridViewLazyAdapter(this, aryFriendList);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_id);
        gv.setAdapter(gridViewLazyAdapter);
        gv.setOnItemClickListener(this);        
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(listener);

        Button btnViewGalary=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnViewGalary);
        btnViewGalary.setOnClickListener(listenerBtnViewGalary);

        Button btnThumbnail=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnThumbnail);
        btnThumbnail.setOnClickListener(listenerBtnThumbnail);
        list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        list.setAdapter(null);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    public OnClickListener listenerBtnViewGalary=new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            gv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    public OnClickListener listenerBtnThumbnail=new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {


            gv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
    {
        if(arg1 == list)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, aryFriendList.get(arg2).getFbId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(Friend_List_Lazy_Loading.this, Post_on_Friend.class);
            i.putExtra("id", ""+aryFriendList.get(arg2).getFbId());
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+aryFriendList.get(arg2).getFbId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(Friend_List_Lazy_Loading.this, Post_on_Friend.class);
            i.putExtra("id", aryFriendList.get(arg2).getFbId());
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello... Have you find your Answer?

Comment: No its not working for me.. can u pls tell me how to fetch friends picture in my code shown above?